# object/json destructuring inside fetch (then)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, fetch-api

Don't know if this is good question since i'm beginner on JavaScript, but i want to use destructuring in fetch api getting error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: response is not iterable

Where is the problem and what is good way to solve it? if possibly could you possibly write two version on with response.json and one without. thanks in advance.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    fetch("https://o", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json",
        "X-API-Key": "***"
      }
    })
      .then((response) => {
        //   response.json().then(function(json) {
        const [b] = response

        //console.log(json)
        console.log(b)
      });
//   })
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably `response` is not an array.

If `response` has a property called `b` then I would try to destructure like the following:

```
const { b } = response;
```

Think about that as the following:

```js
const response = { b: { text: 'text', num: 123 } };
const { b } = response;
console.log(b);
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: I'm getting now 'undefined' when used this 'const { b } = response;
'

Comment: @walee That means `response` does not have a property called `b`. Can you try `console.log(response)` and see what properties you have there?

Comment: @ norbitrial its onjects inside array

Comment: @walee Can you please paste it to here? Thanks!

Comment: const { data } = response

Comment: @norbitrial  [ { "decodedKey": "9s********", "id": "CK****", "currency": { "code": "EUR", "name": "Euro", }, "left": "0" }, { "decodedKey": "9s********", "id": "CK****", "currency": { "code": "EUR", "name": "Euro", }, "left": "0" } ]

Answer (score 0):

if you want, you can also use fetches this way ;

```
fetch(url).then(response => response.json()
.then(data => //you can use whatever action you want to do there
```

The first then returns the response element to you, and you convert this response element to json format. In the second then you access the json format element and use it whatever you want to do.

If you want to know more about this subject, you can search the Promise object.

If you want, you can also use the async-await structure for api requests. It is shorter and more understandable.

```
async function getData(){
const response = await fetch(**your url**);
const data = await response.json();
return data; 
}
```

In this way, the use does the same with the fetch method. Good Luck !